# Corrected 1099 resulted in less income, but now I owe more

Tags: united-states, turbotax, amended-tax-return

I submitted my tax return weeks ago.  And it has since been accepted. However, this morning I received an updated 1099 from my brokerage which resulted in a $1 difference (rounded).   $1 dollar less than before in dividends.  Now TurboxTax says I owe $53.  Does this make any sense to anyone?  And no, the $1 did not put me in a different tax bracket.

Comment: That seems unusual.  It is possible that, in addition to the dollar amount, you have unintentionally recharacterized the dividend from "qualified" to "non-qualified", which would change the tax rate.  I would suggest you try (1) backing out the change to see if it returns to the original tax amount, (2) check your inputs to see if you missed a checkbox or other entry, and (3) re-enter the change in a fresh copy of the original return (to see if you may have made a data entry error).

Comment: Even if the $1 did put you in a different tax bracket, only that dollar would be taxed at the higher rate. Are the 1099's identical but for the amount, or are any amounts in different boxes? Very curious.

Comment: Have you compared the numbers for the entire return to see what boxes/sections  changed?